# Transparent TableView without overlaping elements ios

Tags: objective-c, xcode, uitableview, transparent, ios7

i want to make a transparent table view but the problem is that when the cells go behind the section headers the texts overlapps(see the image:)

http://www.imagebanana.com/view/4lu0pp8s/Bildschirmfoto20130920um13.20.45.png

my idea was to draw the part of the backgroundimage in the header as background but the drawrect method is not updated when the cells are moved.

Hope someone can help me

Comment: Is the header background an image, or some solid color? If it is an image, does it change for each header?

Comment: The head background is clearColor, thats why the cell labels are visible.. i want it transparent to see the blue background image but i do not want to see the cell labels!

Answer (score 0):

You need to trigger a call to `-drawRect:` yourself by calling `-setNeedsDisplay` or `-setNeedsDisplayInRect:` on your header. You will probably want to trigger it based on detecting the position of the header in `-scrollViewDidScroll:`.

Warning: you will want to figure out whether you need to draw the header and then call `-setNeedsDisplay` as infrequently as possible. Bitmap drawing is slow, and can cause the UI to stutter. You should only need to do it when a header row hits the top.

If your header rows are all the same size, cache the image after the first time you draw it, and then just reuse it each subsequent time you need it.

Comment: i tried `-(void)scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)scrollView{
    [[tableView headerViewForSection:0]setNeedsDisplay];
}`but draw rect on the headerview which i subclassed is not called...

Comment: [tableView setNeedsDisplay] is not calling draw rect on the cells right?

Comment: Right - it just calls `-drawRect` on the table view itself.

Comment: Try [-visibleCells](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UITableView_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UITableView/visibleCells) or [-indexPathsForRowsInRect:](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UITableView_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UITableView/indexPathsForRowsInRect:) or [-indexPathsForVisibleRows](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UITableView_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UITableView/indexPathsForVisibleRows).